# Двойное нажатие по browserAction

Tags: javascript, firefox-extension

Появилась идея сделать 2йное нажатие по кнопке на панели инструментов, но или моих знаний не хватает или это вообще не реально.
То есть добавляется кнопка и добавляется listener на onclicked.

```
browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(() => console.log('test'));
```

Понятно, что каждое нажатие вызывается со своим контекстом, но мб есть способ как то перехватить или отследить, что было уже нажато. 
Например: при первом нажатии переменная какая то в true ставится и таймер на 1 секунду, если 2го нажатия нет, то выполняется 1 вариант, а если нажимается 2й раз, то выполняется 2й вариант. или через глобальную типа:

```
let isPressed = false;
browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(() => {
    if(isPressed){
       console.log('action2');
        isPressed = false;
    } else {
        isPressed = true;
        setTimeout(() =>{
            console.log('action1');
            isPressed = false;
        },1000);
    }
})
```

но тут как то отменить предыдущие нужно нажатие тк оно сработает через 1сек.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так можно сделать симуляцию двойного клика.

```js
var isPressed = false;
var timeoutID = null;
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (isPressed) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    timeoutID = null;
    isPressed = false;
    console.log('dblclick');
  } else {
    isPressed = true;
    clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    timeoutID = setTimeout(() => {
      isPressed = false;
      timeoutID = null;
    }, 500);
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">dblclick</button>
```

Comment: да, именно так и сделал. хотел уже сам ответ написать) спасибо